# Show contents of Window in ContentControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, contentcontrol

I have a window named `InstallerView` and wish to display its contents within another window via `ContentControl`.  What is the correct syntax as currently this doesnt work?

```
<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=InstallerView}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="430" />
```

The window is defined as such

```
<Window x:Class="MyBootstrapper.InstallerView" .... >
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the `ContentControl` to display a live view of what's going on in a separate `InstallerView`, at runtime?  Or that you want to embed an `InstallerView` within a `ContentControl` as though it were a usercontrol?

Comment: Embed it as if it were a user control :)

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't just make the content a `UserControl` instead?  And then use that `UserControl` in both of your windows?

Comment: I'm writing an installer using WiX so its currently a Window embedded in a control library, to test its a bit difficult as I have to build the installer and run it outside the debugger so I was hoping for a quick n cheap way to test it by embedded it in another app

Answer (score 0):

Well `InstallerView` is not the name of your window but of your class. So you could do the following, although I don't recommend it.

```
<Grid> <!-- I need a layout control -->
    <Grid.Resources>
        <someNs:InstallerView x:Key="IView" /> 
        <!-- someNs = the namespace of your InstallerView class -->
    </Grid.Resources>
    <!-- Now you can use the resource -->
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource IView}" />
</Grid>
```